# Left alignment of a particular block of equations in the document

Tags: equations, alignment

I have a large number of equations in my thesis. I wish to align a particular block of three equations given below to the left of the page. How shall I do it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{C_row3}
\begin{split}
C31 = &-L_{1}\,d_{3}\,m_{3}\,\dot \theta_1\,\sin\left(\theta_1-\theta_3\right)\\
C35 =& 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
C41 =& -L_{1}\,\dot \theta_1\,\sin\left(\theta_1+\theta_4\right)\,\left(L_{4}\,m_{4}+L_{4}\,m_{5}-d_{4}\,m_{4}\right)\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
C_{51} = &{}-L_{1}\,m_{5}\,\dot \theta_1\,\sin\left(\theta_1+\theta_5\right)\,\left(L_{5}-d_{5}\right)\\
C_{55} =&{} 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fleqn` environment, from `nccmath`, is done for that. It works more or less like `subequations`. Furthermore, you can choose the value of `\displayindent` as an optional argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}
\begin{equation}\label{C_row3}
\begin{split}
C31 = &-L_{1}\,d_{3}\,m_{3}\,\dot \theta_1\,\sin\left(\theta_1-\theta_3\right)\\
C35 =& 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
C41 =& -L_{1}\,\dot \theta_1\,\sin\left(\theta_1+\theta_4\right)\,\left(L_{4}\,m_{4}+L_{4}\,m_{5}-d_{4}\,m_{4}\right)\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
C_{51} = &{}-L_{1}\,m_{5}\,\dot \theta_1\,\sin\left(\theta_1+\theta_5\right)\,\left(L_{5}-d_{5}\right)\\
C_{55} =&{} 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}
\bigskip

\begin{fleqn}[1.5em]
\begin{equation}\label{C_row3}
\begin{split}
C31 = &-L_{1}\,d_{3}\,m_{3}\,\dot \theta_1\,\sin\left(\theta_1-\theta_3\right)\\
C35 =& 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
C41 =& -L_{1}\,\dot \theta_1\,\sin\left(\theta_1+\theta_4\right)\,\left(L_{4}\,m_{4}+L_{4}\,m_{5}-d_{4}\,m_{4}\right)\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
C_{51} = &{}-L_{1}\,m_{5}\,\dot \theta_1\,\sin\left(\theta_1+\theta_5\right)\,\left(L_{5}-d_{5}\right)\\
C_{55} =&{} 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `nccmath` package, you can use `fleqn` environment to achieve what you want:

```
% Preamble
\usepackage{nccmath}

% Body
\begin{fleqn}
% Your equations in here
\end{fleqn}
```